# I'm trying to get the "id" of an html tag, but the xpath doesnt work

Tags: xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using selenium and i want to get the "id" of an html tag with "find_elements_by_xpath", but i've got this error :

> selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid
>   selector: The result of the xpath expression
>   "//body[contains(@class,'de')]/div/div[contains(@class,'container-fluid
>   default')]/section[contains(@id,'mainContent')]/div[contains(@class,'row-fluid')]/div[contains(@id,'contentContainer
>   row-fluid')]/div[contains(@class,'content')]/div[contains(@class,'ses')]/ul/li/@id"
>   is: [object Attr]. It should be an element.

When i executed this code:

```
browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//body[contains(@class,'de')]/div/div[contains(@class,'container-fluid    default')]/section[contains(@id,'mainContent')]/div[contains(@class,'row-fluid')]/div[contains(@id,'contentContainer row-fluid')]/div[contains(@class,'content')]/div[contains(@class,'ses')]/ul/li/@id")
```

While the same code without "/@id" work perfectly but i've got only the text in the "li" tag and it's not what i want.

According to the error, the problem comes from the Xpath.

I expected that this code would return all the "id" that are in "li" html tag, but i got the error.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@id` is an attribute, not an element. The XPath is OK, but the function only returns elements, not attributes. I doubt there's `find_attributes_by_xpath`, but if you want to find the `li` element that has the `@id` defined, you can specify that in the quantifier:

```
browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//body[contains(@class,'de')]
                                /div/div[contains(@class,'container-fluid default')]
                                /section[contains(@id,'mainContent')]
                                /div[contains(@class,'row-fluid')]
                                /div[contains(@id,'contentContainer row-fluid')]
                                /div[contains(@class,'content')]
                                /div[contains(@class,'ses')]/ul/li[@id]")
                                                                  ~~~~~
```

You can then call `element.get_attribute('id')` to retrieve the id of the element.

Comment: Thanks a lot !, now it's working perfectly like i wanted !. 
I didn't understand the difference between elements and attributes, but now it's alright !